# Issue Creating a function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to take this piece of code and put it into a function however it's not printing when I run it, this is the following code I've written, what's missing? Thank you for your help!

```
def pred():   

    with open('AquaticFoodWeb.txt') as input:
        for line in input:
            animal, prey = line.strip().split(' eats ')
            foodweb.setdefault(animal, []).append(prey)

        print ("Predators and Prey:")

        for animal, prey in sorted(foodweb.items()):
            if len(prey) > 1:
                print ("{} eats {} and {}".format(animal, ",     ".join(prey[:-1]), prey[-1]))
            else:
                print ("{} eats {}".format(animal, ", ".join(prey)))


    if __name__ == "__pred__":
        pred()
```

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: If you are actually putting `if __name__ == "__pred__":` inside the function then it won't run. Dedent it to the top level. (And change to `"__main__"` as mentioned above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a python file is executed it is assigned a name. The initial file that is executed via "python file.py" is assigned the name "main" and it is stored under the variable `__name__`. In other cases, say the file is imported ("import file") then `__name__` is assigned a different name.

see [https://docs.python.org/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

```
def pred():   

    with open('AquaticFoodWeb.txt') as input:
        for line in input:
            animal, prey = line.strip().split(' eats ')
            foodweb.setdefault(animal, []).append(prey)

    print ("Predators and Prey:")

    for animal, prey in sorted(foodweb.items()):
        if len(prey) > 1:
            print ("{} eats {} and {}".format(animal, ",     ".join(prey[:-1]), prey[-1]))
        else:
            print ("{} eats {}".format(animal, ", ".join(prey)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pred()
```

Comment: Ohhhhh! Looks like I was relatively close ahah. Your explanation was perfect! Thank you so much!